# Squid file descriptors on Sles15 cannot be increased beyond 4096

Tags: squid

I'm testing squid server on Sles15. In Squid 4.17 on Sles12, we modify the squid.conf with:

```
vsa11074425:/tmp # grep desc /etc/squid/squid.conf
# Squid max_filedescriptors
max_filedescriptors 65536
```

After restart the squid service , I can see it increased  --

```
vsa11074425:/tmp # squidclient -p 8080 mgr:info|grep desc
File descriptor usage for squid:
        Maximum number of file descriptors:   65536
        Largest file desc currently in use:     18
        Number of file desc currently in use:   10
        Available number of file descriptors: 65526
        Reserved number of file descriptors:   100
```

This proxy can support more than 10,000 connections.

For Squid 5.7 on Sles15, I made the same configuration change and restarted the squid service. The max file descriptors did not change and was still 4096:

```
vsa12489936:/tmp # squidclient -p 8080 mgr:info|grep descri
File descriptor usage for squid:
        Maximum number of file descriptors:   4096
        Available number of file descriptors: 4089
        Reserved number of file descriptors:   100
```

I checked the sles15 squid service file. It's 4096 for LimitNOFILE in squid service file on both sles12 and sles15. That number should be overriden by the  max_filedescriptors in squid.conf on squid 4.17/sles12. That number is on the contrary. The service file's value overrides it on squid.conf on squid5.7/sles15...

Why on squid 5.7 on sles15 the max_filedescriptors in squid.conf will be override by LimitNOFILE in service file, and if there's any fix to make squid.conf override service file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

========================

Updated

Yesterday, I updated the /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/squid.service to reset LimitNOFILE from 4096 to 65536. then:

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl stop squid
systemctl start squid

It works, and the "squidclient -p 8080 mgr:info|grep desc" can see the "file descriptors" increased to 65536.

But today, while I'm doing the same update on other 4 squid servers -- no matter how I update  /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/squid.service and how many times restarted the squid service... It's still 4096... no update at all.

Does anyone know what happened? Thanks

========================

Updated

I made another test --

```
systemctl stop squid
nohup /usr/sbin/squid -FC
```

Then I find the "file descriptors" was increased to 65536. This means if not run squid by service, then the squid will read the value from squid.conf and applied.

But after that, I started squid service again:

```
vsa12568974:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants # systemctl start squid
vsa12568974:/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants # squidclient -p 8080 mgr:info|grep desc
File descriptor usage for squid:
        Maximum number of file descriptors:   4096
        Largest file desc currently in use:     14
        Number of file desc currently in use:    7
        Available number of file descriptors: 4089
        Reserved number of file descriptors:   100
```

Comment: i would suggest to open a bugreport, and see what they answer. i did this already for the same product but other issue and it was accept ;) sofar they are working nicely to keep there software bugfree

Comment: Did you check the file descriptors in SLES15 for user which run squid?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Ah...I checked those at first -- the ulimit value, the sysctl -a|grep fs... And tested them with value to higher one -- all no help. Only update that squid.service and restart squid service can help

Comment: @djdomi thanks. would you please tell me how to log bugreport to squid? Thanks

Comment: debian has an built-in way, else you have to look either for a similar solution or or there is, which you could easely found with Google the origin [bug tracker](https://bugs.squid-cache.org/index.cgi)

Comment: @djdomi Thanks. I filed a bug to them -- https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5356